# create an index with floating header in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ka45xgs8/

I need to create a list of games like this but the index (block "List of games") must stay always on top of interface (is not shifted when we click on letter "T", for example). Sothat it is more convenient and faster when we search for different letters. Many thanks ! :)

Comment: `.anchor { position: fixed }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS file:

```
.anchor {
        border:1px solid;
        padding:10px 0px 10px 10px;
        position:fixed;
        width:90%;
        background-color:#009688;
        color:#FFFFFF;
       }
.anchor a{
       color:#FFFFFF;
   }
.content > p > a{
       color:#009688;
   }
.content {
        margin-top:40px;
        position:fixed;
        border: 1px solid;
        padding-left:10px;
        width:90%;
        }
```

HTML File:

```
  <div class="anchor">
    <span style='font-size:15pt'>List of games</span>
      <a href="#go_a">A</a> <a href="#go_b">B</a> 
      <a href="#go_c">C</a>......
      <a href="#go_s">S</a> <a href="#go_T">T</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="content" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:200px;">
    <p><a name="go_a"> <b>A</b> <br>
       Age of Empires   <br>
       Age of Mythology <br>
       American McGee's Alice   <br>
       Anno 1503    <br>
       Ark: Survival Evolved</a></p>

   <p><a name="go_b"><b>B</b><br>
      Battlefield 1942<br>  
      BioShock  <br>
      Black &amp; White <br>
      Blade Runner</a></p>

   <p><a name="go_c"><b>C</b><br>
      Civilization IV   <br>
      Command &amp; Conquer <br>    
      Cossacks II: Napoleonic Wars <br> 
      Counter-Strike</a></p>

     <p><a name="go_s"><b>S</b><br>
       SimCity <br>
       Spore <br>
       Star Wars <br>
       StarCraft    <br>
       Stronghold   <br>
       Supreme Commander</a></p>

    <p><a name="go_T"><b>T</b><br>
       The Binding of Isaac <br>    
       The Legend of Sword and Fairy <br> 
       The Sims <br>    
       The Witcher  <br> 
       Total Annihilation</a></p>
  </div>
```

Demo : https://fiddle.jshell.net/ka45xgs8/3/

Comment: thank you man. I tried to use `position:fixed` for .anchor but did not think about `position:fixed` for .content.

Comment: Please vote the answer by click on up arrow...

Comment: sorry, I dont have enough 15 reputation to do it. :(

Comment: do you have any idea how to move the scrolling bar from .content into outer interface ?

Answer (score 0):

As above, if you want an element to stay in the same position on the page, regardless of scrolling etc., you need to specify the position of the element in your css.

```
.anchor {
border:1px solid;
padding:10px;
position: fixed; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your idea. I tried to use 'position:fixed' already. But only that, it does not work, the block "List of game" will overlap block "content" which is not good.

Comment: Try using this css as a starting point...

   .anchor {
 border:1px solid;
 padding:10px;
 position: fixed;
}
.content {
     border: 1px solid;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    top: 10%;
    height: 400px;
    }

Comment: thank you, yeah, it is solved. I did not think about the `position:fixed` for .content :)